# how to rerun snow leopard server initial configuration wizard again?

Tags: mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard

is there a way to restart the config wizard which goes through the few first steps after you install snow leopard server. is there a way to get that wizard to force run it again at a later date rather than wiping and loading again? thanks.

Comment: Why do you want the wizard to run again?  Is there something in the configuration that you'd like changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changeip command will let you configure the new IP address.

```
Usage: changeip -checkhostname
Usage: changeip <dir node path> <oldIP> <newIP> [<oldHost> <newHost>]
        eg: changeip /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 11.0.1.10 11.0.1.12 server10.example.com server12.example.com


Use - for node path to update the local node only, 
        eg. changeip - 11.0.1.10 11.0.1.12


/usr/sbin/changeip must be run as root
```

Comment: FYI - As of Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard Server, System Preferences' Network pane runs `changeip` automatically, but it's always good to at least run `sudo changeip -checkhostname` to verify.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing this wizard does which can't be changed by System Preferences and Server Admin later is importing the OD configuration from an old server, and this can only be run during initial setup. So, if your problem is about this, you are out of luck, I fear. If your problem is something else, could you please elaborate? There should be a way to do what you want without a reinstall.

Comment: i don't want to run OD again, all i want to do is take it somewhere else and put it in another subnet and re-configure it. i thought that chaging the dhcp scope of the network would just make some of the internal service lookups not work? am i right on assuming that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete /var/db/.AppleSetupDone and restart.